# Windows Server 2012 cannot connect to local domain controller

Tags: domain, windows-server-2012

I've installed Windows Server 2012, and now I'm trying to make it a domain controller. I followed the tutorial here (http://sharepointgeorge.com/2012/configuring-active-directory-ad-ds-in-windows-server-2012/) and I was able to successfully add the AD server role, create the tree for the FOO domain, and promote the server to domain controller.

After the server rebooted, I logged in as administrator in my domain (FOO\administrator).

However, when I go to the Active Directory Administrative Center, it gives me the error, "Cannot connect to any domain. Refresh or try again when connection is available." When I go to Active Directory Users and computers, it says "Naming information cannot be located because: The specified domin either does not exist or could not be contacted..."

I've checked and the Active Directory Domain Services and Active Directory Web Services are both running.

Any ideas?

Edited in from comments (posted by OP):

> DNS is refusing to start. It said "DNS server is waiting for Active
>   Directory Domain Services (AD DS) to signal that the initial
>   synchronization of the directory has been completed." It looks like AD
>   refuses to work because DNS isn't working, and DNS can't start because
>   AD isn't working.

Comment: This is often caused by an incorrect DNS setup. Have you confirmed that ad-integrated DNS was properly initialized?

Comment: I think you're right. DNS is refusing to start. It said "DNS server is waiting for Active Directory Domain Services (AD DS) to signal that the initial synchronization of the directory has been completed." It looks like AD refuses to work because DNS isn't working, and DNS can't start because AD isn't working.

Comment: I"m having this same issue right now, did you ever figure out how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the server's network adapter(s) are set to use the loopback address (127.0.0.1) as their only DNS server (assuming there's no other domain controllers running AD-integrated DNS).

[image: Network adapter DNS settings]

Then, once DNS is running on the server, [setup a *Forwarder* in DNS](https://www.faqforge.com/windows-server-2012-r2/set-dns-forwarder-windows-server-2012-r2/) to forward unknown DNS requests (i.e.: requests for hosts not in your domain) to the public DNS (your ISP's, or OpenDNS, Google's, etc.).

[image: DNS Server Properties]